# Lag with subdivision surface

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

So I started working on Master Chief in Blender and once I got to the point when I needed to make things smooth and realisitc, since that's how he is in the video game of course, everything started lagging. And it's not just for Master Chief. I went back to one of my other files that worked perfectly fine before I got 2.8, which is the version when this started happening, and that file was laggy also. Can someone please explain what is going on.

Comment: So you have a file from 279 that is lagging in 28x? You can post it on bug tracker. Or post the simplified blend that still lagyso we can check.